# Optimization possible or use parallel computing

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, set

I have this problem where I need to find the number of sums of powers that are equal to a number. So for example:

An input of 
`100 2` would yield an output of `3` because `100 = 10^2 = 6^2 + 8^2 = 1^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 7^2` and an input of `100 3` would yield an output of 1 because `100 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3`

So my function for solving this problem is:

```
findNums :: Int -> Int -> Int
findNums a b = length [xs | xs <- (drop 1 .) subsequences [pow x b | x <- [1..c]], foldr (+) (head xs) (tail xs) == a] where c = root a b 0 

root :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
root n a i
    | pow i a <= n && pow (i+1) a > n = i
    | otherwise = root n a (i+1)

pow :: Int -> Int -> Int
pow _ 0 = 1
pow n a = n * pow n (a - 1)
```

I find all the possible values that are able to be in my set of numbers that will add up to the desired number. Then I find all possible sublists inside that list and see how many of those add up to the desired number. This works but since it is an exhaustive search it takes a long time for inputs like `800 2`. Is it possible to optimize the sequences such  that only the "plausible" subsequences are returned? Or is it better to look at parallel computation for this sort of problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's take a tour through a few things.

## Benchmarking

First up: let's make sure we're actually making improvements as we go! For that, we'll need some benchmarks. The [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) package is perfect for this. We'll also make sure to compile with optimizations (so `-O2` on all calls to GHC). Here's how simple setting up a benchmark can be:

```
import Criterion.Main

-- your code goes here

main = defaultMain
    [ bench "findNums 100 2" (nf (uncurry findNums) (100, 2))
    , bench "findNums 800 2" (nf (uncurry findNums) (800, 2))
    ]
```

One could also implement the benchmark as `nf (findNums 100) 2`, but I choose this way so that we can't "cheat" by precomputing a lookup table for `100`, thus pushing all the work into the benchmark setup rather than the part where the benchmark is actually run. Here's the result for the original implementation:

```
benchmarking 100 2
time                 762.7 ns   (757.4 ns .. 768.5 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 762.5 ns   (760.4 ns .. 765.3 ns)
std dev              7.706 ns   (6.378 ns .. 10.59 ns)

benchmarking 800 2
time                 29.17 s    (28.28 s .. 29.87 s)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 29.26 s    (29.08 s .. 29.35 s)
std dev              159.2 ms   (0.0 s .. 165.2 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)
```

## Use libraries

Now, the low-hanging fruit is to use existing implementations of things and hope their authors did something better than us. To that end, we'll use the standard function `(^)` instead of `pow`, and `integerRoot` from the [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi) package instead of `root`. Additionally, we'll swap out the lazy `foldr` for a strict `foldl`. For my own sanity, I also reformatted the very long line into short ones. The full result now looks like this:

```
import Criterion.Main
import Data.List
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers

sum' :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum' = foldl' (+) 0

findNums :: Int -> Int -> Int
findNums a b = length
    [ xs
    | xs <- drop 1 . subsequences $ [x ^ b | x <- [1..c]]
    , sum' xs == a
    ] where c = integerRoot b a

main = defaultMain
    [ bench "100 2" (nf (uncurry findNums) (100, 2))
    , bench "800 2" (nf (uncurry findNums) (800, 2))
    ]
```

Benchmark results look like this now:

```
benchmarking 100 2
time                 722.8 ns   (721.3 ns .. 724.3 ns)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 722.6 ns   (721.4 ns .. 724.1 ns)
std dev              4.440 ns   (3.738 ns .. 5.674 ns)

benchmarking 800 2
time                 17.16 s    (16.93 s .. 17.64 s)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 17.05 s    (16.99 s .. 17.15 s)
std dev              88.10 ms   (0.0 s .. 94.58 ms)
```

A little under twice as fast with very little effort. Nice!

## Better algorithm

A significant problem with `subsequences` is that, even if we compute that `sum' [x,y,z] > a`, we still look at all the longer subsequences that start with `[x,y,z]`. Given the structure of `subsequences`' return type, there's not much we can do about that; so let's design an implementation that gives us a bit more structure. We'll build a tree, where paths from the root to any internal node give us a subsequence.

```
import Data.Tree

subsequences :: [a] -> Forest a
subsequences [] = []
subsequences (x:xs) = Node x rest : rest where
    rest = subsequences xs
```

(Just for fun, this produces exponentially large semantic trees with very small space usage -- roughly as much space as the original list -- due to aggressive subtree sharing.) What's cool about this representation is if we break off the search, we cut off huge swaths of uninteresting results. This can be realized by implementing something like `takeWhile` for lists:

```
takeWhileTree :: Monoid m => (m -> Bool) -> Forest m -> Forest m
takeWhileTree predicate = goForest mempty where
    goForest m forest = forest >>= goTree m
    goTree   m (Node m' children) =
        [Node m (goForest (m <> m') children) | predicate m']
```

Let's give it a try. Complete code is now:

```
import Criterion.Main
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Tree
import Math.NumberTheory.Powers

subsequencesTree :: [a] -> Forest a
subsequencesTree [] = []
subsequencesTree (x:xs) = Node x rest : rest where
    rest = subsequencesTree xs

takeWhileTree :: Monoid m => (m -> Bool) -> Forest m -> Forest m
takeWhileTree predicate = goForest mempty where
    goForest m forest = forest >>= goTree m
    goTree   m (Node m' children) = let m'' = m <> m' in
        [Node m' (goForest m'' children) | predicate m'']

leaves :: Forest a -> [[a]]
leaves [] = [[]]
leaves forest = do
    Node x children <- forest
    xs <- leaves children
    return (x:xs)

findNums :: Int -> Int -> Int
findNums a b = length
    [ xs
    | xs <- leaves
          . takeWhileTree (<= Sum a)
          . subsequencesTree
          $ [Sum (x ^ b) | x <- [1..c]]
    , fold xs == Sum a
    ] where c = integerRoot b a

main = defaultMain
    [ bench "100 2" (nf (uncurry findNums) (100, 2))
    , bench "800 2" (nf (uncurry findNums) (800, 2))
    ]
```

This looks like a lot of work, but from the timings, it really pays off:

```
benchmarking 100 2
time                 16.67 μs   (16.53 μs .. 16.77 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 16.60 μs   (16.52 μs .. 16.72 μs)
std dev              325.4 ns   (270.5 ns .. 444.1 ns)
variance introduced by outliers: 17% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking 800 2
time                 22.59 ms   (22.26 ms .. 22.89 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 22.44 ms   (22.34 ms .. 22.57 ms)
std dev              260.3 μs   (191.6 μs .. 332.2 μs)
```

That's a speedup factor of about 1000 on `findNums 800 2`.

## Parallelization

I had a go at parallelizing this by using `concat` and `parMap` in `takeWhileTree` instead of `(>>=)`, so that separate branches of the tree would be explored in parallel. In every case the overhead of parallelizing far outweighed the benefit of having several threads. Good thing we put that benchmark in place at the beginning!

Comment: Oh my lord. I don't know where to begin to understand whats going on. I understand the purpose of the benchmarking. I understand that you are creating a "Forest" with subsequencesTree. I'll start with that function first. In this part `subsequencesTree (x:xs) = Node x rest : rest where rest = subsequencesTree xs`, I see how you are creating a node but I am not sure how you are placing it inside the forest. Is there an in depth explanation for this behavior?

Comment: @user2977382 Well, `type Forest a = [Tree a]`, right? So a forest is just a list of trees. And the subsequences of `xs` either include the first element of `xs` or they don't. So `Node x rest` is a tree where all paths start with the element `x`, and `rest` is a forest where each tree has paths that don't start with `x`. And `Node x rest : rest` is the forest that includes both -- hence has paths that include `x` and paths that don't.

Comment: Okay, this tree constructs all the possible sequences? And you are sifting out the relevant trees with takeWhileTree based on the predicate of the sum of the tree being less than a?

Comment: Kind of unrelated but I had a question on Monoids and Monads that I would like clarification on. From what I think I understand is that Monoids are functors that map objects to objects inside of a group? Monads are a subset of Monoids where the objects are functions? Is this thinking correct?

Comment: @user2977382 That is probably worth fleshing out into a complete question on MathOverflow, or perhaps even here in the haskell tag of StackOverflow. A comment can't really do the question justice (I'm not sure I understand your proposed equivalences yet) and certainly won't do the answer justice. In particular, the kinds of monoids and monads don't match, so any statement like "monoids are monads" or "monads are monoids" are going to need a bit of careful detail to make sense.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest, there is some room for optimization here without resorting to parallelizing things (which, keep in mind, can at best give a 4x speedup if you're going from one to four parallel threads).

What the `subsequences` function is doing is essentially going through the list, and for each element it creates two execution branches: one where that element is included, and one where it isn't. I.e., `subsequences [1,2,3]` does:

```
                           start
                   /-------/   \-------\         (take 1 or not)
             [1,..]                    [..]
            /      \                  /    \     (take 2 or not)
    [1,2,..]        [1,..]       [2,..]    [..]
      /  \           /  \         /  \     /  \  (take 3 or not)
[1,2,3]  [1,2]   [1,3]  [1]   [2,3]  [2] [3]  []
```

The result of `subsequences [1,2,3]` is then a list containing the leaf nodes at the bottom.

Now, at each of the intermediate nodes (i.e. `[1,2,..]`), we can check the result of applying the value function (i.e., the sum of squares or cubes or etc.) to the numbers already taken. If we're already above the target, there's no point in continuing that branch. If we write this subsequence generation logic by ourselves, we can do that:

```
findNums :: Int -> Int -> Int
findNums a b = findNums' a b 1 0

findNums' :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
findNums' a b c s
  | s + c^b > a  = 0
  | s + c^b == a = 1
  | otherwise    = findNums' a b (c+1) (s + c^b) +
                   findNums' a b (c+1) s
```

Here `c` is our counter and `s` is the sum of the powers of the numbers we have picked. There are three cases in `findNums'`:

In the first case, we check whether including this number would make us go above target. In that case, this branch is not going to give any valid results, so we terminate it and indicate that it contains no solution by returning 0.

In the second case, we check whether including this number would put us right on spot. In that case we return 1, essentially noting that we have found a solution.

If none of these are true, we recurse further with two different branches: one where we add `c^b` to our sum, and one where we refrain from doing so. We add the results together, which means that the result here will be the number of branches below this point that have found a valid solution.

Comment: I see. So building the branches where the element is exponentiated and when it is not takes care of all the possible subsequences? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is useful to write a function which returns
the actual sequences because that function can be written
recursively in terms of itself.

To simplify things, let's just consider sums of squares.
Also, we will first consider ordered sequences (with
repeated values allowed); later we will look at how to modify the
algorithm to produce only unordered sequences without any repeated
numbers.

Here is our first attempt. The algorithm is based on this idea:

> Idea 1:
>
> To obtain a sequence whose sum of squares is *n*, first
>   pick a value *c* and a sequence *xs* whose sum of squares
>   is *n-c*c* and put the two together.

```
 -- an integer sqrt function
 isqrt n = floor $ (sqrt (fromIntegral n) :: Double)

 pows2a :: Int -> [ [Int] ]
 pows2a n
   | n < 0     = []
   | n == 0    = [ [] ]
   | otherwise = [ (c:xs) | c <- [start,start-1..1], xs <- pows2a (n-c*c) ]
     where start = isqrt n
```

This works, but returns permutations of solutions as well as solutions with
repeated elements - e.g. `pos2a 6` returns `[2,1,1]`, `[1,2,1]`, `[1,1,2]` and `[1,1,1,1,1,1]`.

To only return unordered sequences (without repetition) we
use this idea:

> Idea 2:
>
> To obtain a sequence whose sum of squares is *n*, first
>   pick a value *c* and a sequence *xs* whose sum of squares
>   is *n-c*c* and all of whose elements are < *c* and
>   put the two together.

This is just a slight modification of our first algorithm:

```
 pows2b :: Int -> [[Int]]
 pows2b n
   | n < 0     = []
   | n == 0    = [ [] ]
   | otherwise =  [ (c:xs) | c <- [start, start-1..1], xs <- pows2b (n-c*c), all (< c) xs ]
   where
     start = isqrt n
```

This works but a call like `pows2b 100` takes a long time to complete because we are making calls to `pows2b` with the same argument multiple times.

We can solve that problem by memoizing the results, and this is what `pows2c` does:

```
 powslist = map pows2c [0..]
 pows2c n
   | n == 0    = [ [] ]
   | otherwise = [ (c:xs) | c <- [s,s-1..1], xs <- powslist !! (n-c*c), all (< c) xs ]
   where s = isqrt n
```

Here the recursive call with argument `n-c*c` is replaced by a lookup into a list which is a way of caching the answer.