# Haskell: can I use laziness to "abort early" and gain performance?

Tags: haskell, optimization, lazy-evaluation

I'm writing a Haskell program that reads a wordlist of the English language and a rectangular grid of letters such as:

```
I T O L
I H W S
N H I S
K T S I
```

and then finds a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) through the grid from the top-left corner that spells out a sequence of English words, such as:

```hs
--> $ runghc unpacking.hs < 4x4grid.txt
I THINK THIS IS SLOW
```

(If there are multiple solutions, it can just print any one it finds and stop looking.)

The naïve, strict approach is to generate a full path and then try to split it up into words. However, assuming that I'm doing this (and currently I am forcing myself to -- see below) I'm spending a lot of time finding paths like:

```hs
IINHHTOL...
IINHHTOW...
IINHHWOL...
```

These are obviously never going to turn out to be words, looking at the first few letters (`"IINH"` can't be split into words, and no English word contains `"NHH"`.) So, say, in the above grid, I don't want to look at the many<sup>[1]</sup> paths that begin with `IINHH`.

Now, my functions look like this:

```hs
paths :: Coord -> Coord -> [[Coord]]
paths (w, h) (1, 1) = [[(1, 1), (1, 2), ... (x, y)], ...]

lexes :: Set String -> String -> [[String]]
lexes englishWordset "ITHINKTHISWILLWORK" = [["I", "THINK", "THIS", ...], ...]
```

`paths` just finds all the paths worth considering on a `(w, h)` grid. `lexes` finds all the ways to chop a phrase up, and is defined as:

```hs
lexes language [] = [[]]
lexes language phrase = let
  splits = tail $ zip (inits phrase) (tails phrase)
  in concat [map (w:) (lexes language p') | (w, p') <- splits,
             w `S.member` language]
```

Given `"SAMPLESTRING"`, it looks at `"S"`, then `"SA"`, then `"SAM"`... as soon as it finds a valid word, it recurses and tries to "lex" the rest of the string. (First it will recurse on `"PLESTRING"` and try to make phrases with `"SAM"`, but find no way to chop "plestring" up into words, and fail; then it will find `["SAMPLE", "STRING"]`.)

Of course, for an invalid string above, any hope of being "lazy" is lost by following this approach: in the example from earlier we need to still search beyond a ridiculous phrase like `"ITOLSHINHISIST"`, because maybe `"ITOLSHINHISISTK"` (one letter longer) *might* form a valid single word.

I feel like somehow I could use laziness here to improve performance throughout the entire program: if the first few characters of `phrase` aren't a prefix of *any* word, we can bail out entirely, stop evaluating the rest of `phrase`, and thus the rest of the path.<sup>[2]</sup> Does this make sense at all? Is there some tree-like data structure that will help me check not for set membership, but set "prefix-ness", thereby making checking validity lazier?

<sup>[1] Obviously, for a 4x4 grid there are very few of these, but this argument is about the general case: for bigger grids I could skip hundreds of thousands of paths the moment I see they start with "JX".

[2] `phrase` is just `map (grid M.!) path` for some `Map Coord Char` `grid` read from the input file.</sup>

Comment: You might want to consider tries and related structures.

Comment: You might like the "Better algorithm" section of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27893057/791604), which discusses how to turn a function that produces a list of candidates into a function that produces a tree of candidates, which can then be more effectively pruned. You could take a similar route with your `paths` function: instead of returning a list of paths, return a tree, and then cut off subtrees of paths that don't lex early on.

Comment: The fastest solution here would be searching a [DAWG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_acyclic_finite_state_automaton) of the dictionary.

Comment: As for the "how do I know when I'm in a prefix that can't be salvaged" part: just use the regular language `(i|think|this|will|work)*` (where you include all words in the English language inside the parentheses). Just about everything about regular languages is decidable -- including whether the DFA for it is currently in a "dead state" that can never reach a final state.

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far. I was vaguely imagining some sort of mix between a DFA and a tree that could help me out, and the DAWG seems to be exactly that. I'll see if that helps me out.

Comment: Oh, @DanielWagner mentioned `criterion` in his linked answer, which looks neat, too! I'm going to give that a try (I was doing bad benchmarks with the Unix `time` command.)